# Populate each null element with other Array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm facing a hard time understanding arrays. I have two of them, which I want to pick one and populate null elements with the other array elements. I currently have the below:

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4]
var arr2 = [null, 99, null, null]

arr2.map((item) => {
  if (item == null) {
    arr2 = arr1.splice(item, 1)
  }
})

console.log(arr2)
// is outputing [3]. Expected is 1, 99, 3, 4
```

I'm using `splice` as I see it as the most close method I can use to accomplish my goal. Also, `.map` is used but not a requirement.

I'll happy visit any related/already answered question, but since English is not my main language, I couldn't find any related question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is going to call `splice(null, 1)` on `arr1` and assign the result *on top of* the entire `arr2` three times.

`map` is designed to allow you to go through each item in an array and provide a substitute for each item, but you need to use it correctly, like this:

```js
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4]
var arr2 = [null, 99, null, null]

arr2 = arr2.map((item, i) => item === null ? arr1[i] : item )

console.log(arr2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just avoid the splice, and take the value you need with a ternary operator:

```js
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4]
var arr2 = [null, 99, null, null]

arr2 = arr2.map( (item, i) => item === null ? arr1[i] : item );

console.log(arr2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, but the callback in `map` is supposed to return the element to be used in the new array.  Try this instead.

```
arr2 = arr2.map((value, index) =>
    value != null ? value : arr1[index]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that `arr1` and `arr2` have same size you could do

```
for(var i=0;i<arr2.length;i++){
  arr2[i]= arr2[i] || arr1[i];
}
```

I am using the `for` loop because it's ideal if you're just beginning working with arrays in order to fully understand how they work.
The `||` operator, also known as null-coalescing operator, returns the first truthy operand to the assignment.

Comment: This would probably produce an undesired result if `arr2` contained any `0`s.